# Use /dev/shm sometimes crashes applications

Tags: memory, dev

Sometimes I use `/dev/shm` for temporary files, as big as 500MB, (I have 8 GB RAM - Ubuntu 11.04 x86-64) and when I load StarCraft II (with wine) I might get *memory* errors in the game (corrupted data or "Couldn't load *xyz*").

If instead I use *proper* temporary filesystem for my files (like and SSD disk mounted on `/disk3`) I don't experience any sort of issue.

Could this be due to the fact that `/dev/shm` gets continuously filled and emptied whilst SC2 (or other programs here) expect to have some available memory and hence `malloc` fails (and the process then reports *errors* where it before expected to have some available memory)?

I'm really puzzled by this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have heard, the GNU libc has its own semantics on `/dev/shm/` and as a user (or local admin) you are supposed to not use it yourself at all.

Also, it’s size-limited in most distributions.

And yes, something like `Wine` will use lots of shared memory, that also eats up `/dev/shm`.

I suggest to mount a `tmpfs` onto someplace else (in fact, I recommend running systems with `/tmp` as `tmpfs` and using `TMPDIR=/var/tmp` for things that need a larger scratch space).